# How to concatenate a string and an integer inside a conditional function in Impala

Tags: hive, impala

In `hive`

```
select concat("Positive", 123);

Positive123
```

```
select if("Positive" in ('Negative', 'No', 'Sub-zero'), 123, concat("Positive",123));

Positive123
```

But in `Impala`:

```
select concat("Positive", 123);

AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: concat(STRING, TINYINT).
```

Using [CAST](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/impala_conversion_functions.html#conversion_functions__cast) works:

```
select concat("Positive", cast(123 as string));

Positive123
```

But

```
select if("Positive" in ('Negative', 'No', 'Sub-zero'),
          123,
          concat("Positive", cast(123 as string))
          );

AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: if(BOOLEAN, TINYINT, STRING).
```

How can I concatenate a string and an integer inside a conditional function if in Impala?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the error you are facing.

> No matching function with signature: if(BOOLEAN, **TINYINT**, STRING).

You need to convert everything to one single type of data type - like string. So, solution is to cast the true case to string as well.
So here is how you can rewrite the SQL.

```
select if("Positive" in ('Negative', 'No', 'Sub-zero'),
          cast(123 as string),  -- cast the true case to string.
          concat("Positive", cast(123 as string))
          );
```

Impala is very bad in converting data types automatically.